# Uniform distribution inside a binomial distribution

Tags: statistics

Suppose that three contestants on a quiz show are each given the same question,
and that each answers it correctly, independently of the others, with probability P. The
diculty P of the question is itself a random variable which is uniformly distributed on
(0; 1].

(a) What is the probability that exactly two of the contestants answer the questions
correctly?

So I took X = # people that answer correctly $X \sim Bin(3, P \sim unif(0,1])$

Should I use an integral inside an integral?

How do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use $Y$ instead of $P$ (since $P$ is usually denoting the probability): You're given that $Y\sim\mathrm{unif}(0,1)$ and that $X\mid Y=p\sim\mathrm{bin}(3,p)$, that is
$$
P(X=2\mid Y=p)=\binom{3}{2}p^2(1-p)^{3-2},\quad p\in (0,1).
$$
Then you find $P(X=2)$ by the formula
$$
P(X=2)={\rm E}[P(X=2\mid Y)]=\int_0^1P(X=2\mid Y=p)\,f_Y(p)\,\mathrm dp,
$$
where $f_Y$ is the density of $Y$.

Comment: I get the answer, but why is
$$
P(X=2) = E[P(X=2|Y)]
$$
??
Ohwait nevermind, I proved that already. Thanks!